# Critique my simple Java quiz program

Tags: java, eclipse

This is my first post here, so apologies in advance if this is an off-topic subject or my presentation of the details is rough. I'm teaching myself Java and wrote some code to experiment with defining a reference type and methods acting on it, and, while it works, I have no idea whether there may be much better, more efficient ways to accomplish what I've done. I wanted at least one method that returned a value (here checking whether the answer to the question is correct), and to use static variables to track what's happening over the course of generating multiple instances of the class (here tracking the number of questions answered and the number answered correctly). The code generates a quiz of division problems.

Here's the code, also posted at [GitHub](https://github.com/Asalancy/JavaDivisionQuiz):

Defining the reference type DivisionProblem, with divisor btw 5 and 14 and quotient btw 2 and 11, with methods to generate the values for the problem, to state the problem in the console (I'm using Eclipse if that's helpful), to check whether an answer is correct, to act on right and wrong answers, and to track overall performance:

```
import java.util.Random;

class DivisionProblem {

    int dividend, divisor, quotient;
    static int answered=0, answeredRight=0;

    void generate() {
        Random myRandom = new Random();
        divisor = myRandom.nextInt(10) + 5;
        quotient = myRandom.nextInt(10) + 2;
        dividend=divisor*quotient;
    }
    void stateProblem() {
        System.out.print("What is " + dividend + " divided by " + quotient + "?");
    }
    boolean checkAnswerTF(int answer) {
        return answer == divisor;
    }
    void rightAnswer() {
        ++answered;
        ++answeredRight;
        System.out.println("That's right!");
    }
    void wrongAnswer() {
        ++answered;
        System.out.println("No, the answer is "+ divisor);          
    }
    void statePerformance() {
        System.out.print("You have answered " + answeredRight + " of " + answered + " questions correctly. ");
    }
}
```

And here's the class that makes use of the DivisionProblem type:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DivisionQuiz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char reply;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        DivisionProblem aDivisionProblem;

        do {
            aDivisionProblem = new DivisionProblem();           
            aDivisionProblem.generate();
            aDivisionProblem.stateProblem();
            if (aDivisionProblem.checkAnswerTF(keyboard.nextInt())) {
                aDivisionProblem.rightAnswer();
            }   else    {
                aDivisionProblem.wrongAnswer();
            };
            aDivisionProblem.statePerformance();

            System.out.println("Another problem? Type Y for yes.");
            reply = keyboard.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);

        } while (reply == 'Y'||reply == 'y');       
        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

Here's sample output:

```
What is 112 divided by 8?14
That's right!
You have answered 1 of 1 questions correctly. Another problem? Type Y for yes.
y
What is 80 divided by 8?10
That's right!
You have answered 2 of 2 questions correctly. Another problem? Type Y for yes.
y
What is 130 divided by 10?12
No, the answer is 13
You have answered 2 of 3 questions correctly. Another problem? Type Y for yes.
y
What is 21 divided by 3?7
That's right!
You have answered 3 of 4 questions correctly. Another problem? Type Y for yes.
n
```

Any and all suggestions for improvement are welcome. I'm thinking of learning JavaFX and getting this out of the Eclipse console next.

Comment: code review *might* be a better place for this question, but not in its current state -- you'd want to improve it by being much more specific with your questions.

Comment: You have separated the `DivisionProblem` code into many methods, that’s basically a good thing for finding my way through it, you may be overdoing it a slight bit. I think in the output I’d put a space after the question mark, then it’s easier to read the answer if you want to review your past performance. Generally it’s a very nice solution to the problem.

Comment: Hovercraft: Thanks for the feedback! Is there a code review section on Stack Overflow or are you referring to another site?

Comment: Ole: Yes, I separated it so that I could try out returning a value and playing with static type variables. Thanks for the confirmation on the approach.

Comment: I believe @HovercraftFullOfEels intends https://codereview.stackexchange.com.